# How to close connection in node js mssql?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest

I'm using `mssql` npm for connecting to SQL Server. When I connect to the database and get or post data, the connection is open yet. How can I close the connection after each request?

This is a kind of request I use:

```
router.get('/getnotification/:userid',async(req,resp,next)=>{
    (async function(){
        let pool = null;
        try{
            pool = await connection
            let result = await pool.request()
            .input('input_id',sql.BigInt,req.params.userid)
            .query(`exec showNotification 0,@input_id`)

            if(result){
                resp.status(200).send(result.recordset).end;
            }
            //  pool.close()
        }catch(err){
                resp.status(500).send(err).end;
            //  pool.close()  
        }

    })()
})
```

I also use `pool.close()` after request is done but for next request connection is closed.

Comment: Reopen connection for each request or https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#advanced-pool-management

Comment: Documentation says: "you should aim to only close a pool when you know it will never be needed by the application again; typically this will be when your application is shutting down".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a middleware function for closing a pool and use it after bind `pool` to req obj,

```
const closePoolMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {

  if(!req.pool) {
    next("pass error to express")
  }
  req.pool.close()
  next()
})
```

and then,

```
router.get('/getnotification/:userid',async(req,resp,next)=>{
    (async function(){
        let pool = null;
        try{
            pool = await connection
            let result = await pool.request()
            .input('input_id',sql.BigInt,req.params.userid)
            .query(`exec showNotification 0,@input_id`)

            if(result){
                resp.status(200).send(result.recordset).end;
            }
            //  pool.close()
        }catch(err){
                resp.status(500).send(err).end;
            //  pool.close()  
        }

    })()
}, closePoolMiddleware)
```